# How to change the size of a JLabel and JTextfield?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield, layout-manager

I am simply trying to change the actual size of my `JLabel` and `JTextField`. At the moment I have them on a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`. I just want the label and the textfield right next to one another in each row.

Right now they're so spread out because my `JLabel` is huge even though I want it very small. I have tried using `setPreferredSize()` and `setSize()`, but their sizes do not change. I just want them set to 30.

Can someone please provide some insight into my dilemma?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (i.e. include your, well formatted, code in your question). The current state of your question will lead to multiple questions being asked in the comments section or your question will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Components in a `GridLayout` are all assigned the same size (as wide as the widest, as tall as the tallest). This can be fixed by using an alternate layout (e.g. `GridBagLayout`).

> I just want the label and the textfield right next to one another in each row.

But we can 'cheat' here in that only the text (and icon) of a `JLabel` is visible. I.E. it has no visible border. To do that, ensure that the text of the label is aligned to the side closest to the component that it needs to be adjacent to.

But I'd probably go for the `GridBagLayout` approach. It will only assign as much space as required for the widest label in that column.

Answer (score -1):

For changing the size `JFrame` you can write this

```
myJFrame.setSize(30,30)
```

For changing the size of fonts in `JTextField` you can write this:

```
myJLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 30))
```

Comment: OP stated in the question that `setSize(...)` changes nothing. Changing the font of a `JTextField` may change it's height, but not to a reliably exact amount, especially not from one OS to another. OP should use a layout manager that takes preferred sizes into account, such as `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: yes, the  class GridBagLayout helps him in arranges the components in a horizontal and vertical manner. But it cant not do anything with the size of the fonts in the JLabel text

Comment: right, but OP did not specify if the font size of the `JLabel` is huge or if the `JLabel` itself is huge. Either way, using a layout manager that respects `setPreferredSize(...)` will *fix* the latter and illuminate the former.

Comment: the font size within the jlabel and the jtexfield is currently set to 30, and 20 respectively.

Comment: `myJLabel.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.BOLD, 30))` Less fragile as to the particular font (Calibri) being installed is `label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(30f).deriveFont(Font.BOLD))`